# MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) Freezes & Crashes too much

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro keeps freezing:

- Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
- Processor: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- OS: Mojave 10.14.6

I tried:

1. Ran **Apple Diagnostics** => No issues
2. Changed setting: System Preferences => Energy Saver => **uncheck** Put hard disks to sleep when possible
3. Reset **NVRAM**

But all of it does not work. It makes me annoyed when working.
Some of System Reports:

**Report 1**

```
Anonymous UUID:       CB5DA94F-785C-BD13-EF7B-5C4FB2C1FC01

Mon Feb 24 12:52:10 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80128bb9af):  initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none

uuid info:
 0x114a24000    uuid = <615654d5-b6c5-3d83-a146-34a3ea6d3a80>
 0x10b67b000    uuid = <bbd445b6-fba9-3a9c-828f-a112f63e2080>

Thread 2 crashed

RAX: 0x0000002000000000, RBX: 0x00007ffd08400020, RCX: 0x000070000fedd360, RDX: 0x000000010b67b000
RSP: 0x000070000fedd210, RBP: 0x000070000fedd2c0, RSI: 0x000000010b69cc1f, RDI: 0x00007fffde6ffc3c
R8:  0x000070000fedd4d0, R9:  0x000070000fedd298, R10: 0x00007fff669c7aa3, R11: 0x0000000000000202
R12: 0xfffffffffffff000, R13: 0x00007fff9d062a68, R14: 0x000070000fedd308, R15: 0x00007ffd084002b0
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0x00007fff667c6920, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff8032e91000
    0x00007fff66912126
    0x00007fff6679bede
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 1: 0xffffff804d1b5520
    0x00007fff6692d29e
    0x00007fff6678ede6
    0x00007fff6679df42
    0x00007fff66792792
    0x00007fff66793396
    0x00007fff6679b6ed
    0x00007fff669cc611
    0x00007fff669cc3fd
    0x0000000000070507

Thread 2: 0xffffff8039478000
    0x00007fff667c6920
    0x00007fff667d86e6
    0x00007fff667c6839
    0x00007fff667c66ab
    0x00007fff667d79d9
    0x00007fff667d78d1
    0x00007fff66834b2a
    0x000000010b69cc1f
    0x000000010b6ad439
    0x00007fff6678c63d
    0x00007fff6678ede6
    0x00007fff6679df42
    0x00007fff66792792
    0x00007fff66793396
    0x00007fff6679b6ed
    0x00007fff669cc611
    0x00007fff669cc3fd
    0x0000000000070507

Thread 3: 0xffffff8050ff7520
    0x00007fff669cc3f0

Thread 4: 0xffffff8044e46000
    0x00007fff669cc3f0


Mac OS version:
18G1012

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sat Oct 12 00:02:19 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DFB5D0E2-3B41-3647-A48B-D704AFCC06B4
System model name: MacBookPro11,4 (Mac-06F11FD93F0323C5)
Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."

EOF

System Profile:
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
Boot Volume File System Type: apfs
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
Model: MacBookPro11,4, BootROM 195.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.29f24
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisProItem, Intel Iris Pro, spdisplays_builtin
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.3 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Model: MacBookPro11,4, BootROM 195.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.29f24
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisProItem, Intel Iris Pro, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.3 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is something that we have to see

> Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts.
>   Terminating."

Try turning off this setting.

1. **Open System Preferences > Energy Saver**
2. **Untick *Put hard disks to sleep when possible* on both the Battery and Power Adapter tab.**

Check [MikeSchubert](http://mikeschubert.com/2018/01/28/could-not-recover-sata-hdd-after-5-attempts-terminating/) blog for more detail.

In addition, you can test another solution as

This kind of system report states the fans' internal sensor isn't working anymore. Set the automatic controls using the Macs Fan Control app.

Made the fans come on when the processors got to around 55 C and set the maximum RPM of the fans to just shy off the top. And that’s it. It also prevent them from re-starting.